# Asp.Net CORS security issue

Tags: api, asp.net-core, cross-domain

I made a CORS policy in my asp.net core API, but it seems the API is accessible for the public, as I can see the JSON by just typing the API URL in browser. So I just want my front-end(which is a angular app in the same host of API) have access to API not everyone.
this is my start up class:

```
public class Startup
{
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("myurl")
                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                   .AllowAnyMethod(); 
                              });
        });
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
        });

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
        });

        services.AddControllers();
        string connectionString = "xxx";
        services.AddDbContext<decorContext>(
          option => option.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            );
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
       
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
       
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ,@"StaticFiles")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
        });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is kicked in when Domain A accesses Domain B (like making an ajax call in js) and it won't apply when you hit the url directly. That's why it's called CROSS-ORIGIN.

You don't typically implement "script -> website" restriction. You could restrict access by location/IP, user identity/role/claims, or by checking if antiforgery token is present in a request. Check out [Overview of ASP.NET Core Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: my bad miss understanding! so it works as the way  it supposed to, thank you for clarifying I m knew to API writing.